# Appending maps to a map in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to build a map[string]map[string]string which will look something like this:

```
{ "notes": 
    {
    "Title":note.Title,
    "Body":note.Body,
    },
    {
    "Title":note.Title,
    "Body":note.Body,
    },
    {
    "Title":note.Title,
    "Body":note.Body,
    },
}
```

from a struct (notes) of structs (note)

I have thought of doing it like this:

```
for _, note := range notes {
        thisNote := map[string]string{
            "Title":note.Title,
            "Body":note.Body,
        }

        content["notes"] = append(content["notes"], thisNote)
}
```

But obviously that is not going to work because I am trying to append a map to a map rather than a slice.

Is there a really easy solution to this that I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean you're building a map[string][]map[string]string?

Comment: I'm trying to build a map to pass to Moustache (template engine), it requires an identifier ("Notes") and maps of values. So I guess yes, I don't funny understand the difference (I am very new to Go)

Comment: Well I don't know anything about Moustache, but if the data is really as you describe then you should try a map[string][]map[string]string, certainly your append will work in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can use a struct like this instead since mustache receives the data as an `interface{}`

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var data struct {
        Notes []*Note
    }

    notes := ...
    data.Notes = notes
    tmpl := ...
    templ.Render(data, w)
}
```

Comment: I realise that this is something someone unfamiliar with Moustache (and my question was not very specific) could not have answered, but this names my life so much easier! I didn't realise those can be passed directly!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Running Wild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296466/running-wild) for this answer, it was in a comment but I thought I would add it here for anyone trying to do the same thing.

The issue was that I needed to make a `map[string][]map[string]string` rather than a `map[string]map[string]string`